# Conclusion about Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $f \in X^*$ a linear functional with $||f||=1$.

Let $B(X,Y)$ be the set of all bounded linear transformations from $X$ to $Y$.

Define $T:Y \to B(X,Y)$ by $(Ty)(x) = f(x)y$.

I have showed that $T$ is an isometry (That is - linear and preserves norm).

I need to conclude that if $B(X,Y)$ is Banach then so is $Y$ .

Im not sure how - one approach is to say that $T(Y)$ is a closed subset of $B(X,Y)$ but im not sure how to do that(if it's true).

Another approach is to take $\{y_n\} \subset Y$ cauchy sequence, then $T(y_n) $ is also a cuachy sequence since $T$ is isometry, so it converges, but this does not imply that $\{y_n\}$ also converge.

Any ideas?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof without using completion. Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Then $T(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B(X,Y)$ and because it is a Banach space we know there is a function $\phi\in B(X,Y)$ such that $T(y_n)\to\phi$. Also, there is a vector $x_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)=1$. And finally, convergence in norm implies strong convergence. Hence:

$\phi(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} T(y_n)(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_0)y_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$

So the sequence $y_n$ has a limit.

Comment: what do you mean by "convergence in norm implies strong convergence"?

Comment: $T(y_n)\to\phi$ in norm means that $||T(y_n)-\phi||\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. Strong convergence means that for any point $x\in X$ we have $T(y_n)(x)\to\phi(x)$ when $n\to\infty$. Obviously convergence in norm implies strong convergence, it easily follows from the definition of the norm in $B(X,Y)$.

Comment: I guess that this is  $||Ty_n -\phi|| \to 0$ implies that for each $x$ $||Ty_n(x) - \phi(x) || \to 0$ , any chance you could explain why this is true?

Comment: It is true because $||T(y_n)(x)-\phi(x)||_Y=||(T(y_n)-\phi)(x)||_Y\leq ||T(y_n)-\phi||\times ||x||_X\to 0$.

Comment: Ahh!  of course... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\widetilde{Y}$ be the completion of $Y$, which is a Banach space.  We have

$$B(X,Y) \subset B(X, \widetilde{Y})$$

as a normed subspace.  Let $y_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, converging to some $y \in \widetilde{Y}$.  You want to show that $y$ is actually in $Y$.

The operators $T(y_n)$ converge to $T(y)$ in $B(X,\widetilde{Y})$.  But if $B(X,Y)$ is a Banach space, then $T(y)$ must actually lie in $B(X,Y)$.  Hence $y$ must be in $Y$.

(I would be interested in seeing a proof where we don't make use of $Y$ being contained in a completion).